# React redundant prop validation

Tags: javascript, validation, reactjs, properties

In React you can specify which one props are required and which types they should have. Is there possibility to display validation warning when unknown prop names (for example unspecified in propTypes) are passed to component?

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html

Answer (score 3):

With a higher-order component anything is possible:

```
// This is not a full solution, merely a sketch of one way to do it
const OnlyValidProps = WrappedComponent => {
  return class extends React.Component {
    render() {
      const actualProps = Object.keys(this.props);
      const expectedProps = Object.keys(WrappedComponent.propTypes);
      const hasPropMisMatch = (
        actualProps.length != expectedProps.length ||
        !actualProps.every(key => expectedProps.contains(key))
      );
      if (hasPropMisMatch) {
        console.warn(`Props mismatch! expected: ${expectedProps} actual: ${actualProps}`);
      }
      return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />;
    }
  };
}

// Usage
OnlyValidProps(class MyClass extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    x: React.PropTypes.number,
    y: React.PropTypes.number
  }
});
```

Comment: You'd have to remember to call whatever method it was before you returned your components in `render`, but yes, it most certainly would.

Comment: I meant by having a render method in the base class that did the checking and subclasses would call super.render from their render method. I was really wondering if there are benefits from doing it either way.

Comment: Wouldn't be very clear because you'd call `super.render()` but ignore the return value ... but you *could* do it.